# REGEXEXTRACT before a group of characters in google sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula

I have this google sheets table with input in column `A` I need this output on the right.

| Input | Desired Output |
| --- | --- |
| "https://www.example.com/sub.php?id=54128754" | https://www.example.com/sub.php?id=54128754 |
| "https://www.example.com/sub-new-45184832/" | https://www.example.com/sub-new-45184832 |
| "https://www.example.com/sub-new2-495174885/" | https://www.example.com/sub-new2-495174885 |

But when trying this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A4, "(.+)[\""|\/]"))
```

This is what I came up with.

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| "https://www.example.com/sub.php?id=54128754" | "https://www.example.com/sub.php?id=54128754 |
| "https://www.example.com/sub-new-45184832/" | "https://www.example.com/sub-new-45184832/ |
| "https://www.example.com/sub-new2-495174885/" | "https://www.example.com/sub-new2-495174885/ |

How to extract everything between `"(*)"`, or `"(*)/"`.
In other word if ended with `"` or `/"`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3, """(.+?)(?:\/)?"""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The regex is simple:

- start with `"`: `^"`
- capture `()` anything but `"`: `[^"]`
- ends with `"`: `"$`
- Since, `"` is a  argument delimiter, we need to escape `"` by doubling it: `""`.

##### Regex:

```
"^""([^""]+)""$"
```

If you want to remove the last `/` as well, make the capture group non-greedy(`+?`) and add `/` before the `"` as optional:

```
"^""([^""]+?)/?""$"
```